# Can't find variable: Buffer

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, global-variables

I'm trying to use node modules in my react-native app, and I'm taking the [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/) approach here.

I'm all set up now, and I got the crypto package to load in fine. However when I added in [eth-lightwallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-lightwallet) things have been getting weird.

Every since I added that package in, npm hasn't been installing dependancies of anything. Meaning I've had to add them in manually. And everytime I install a dependency somehow related to eth-lightwallet, that module is uninstalled. Although tedious and annoying, I'm hoping it can shed light onto my current problem.

Right now I'm running into a `Can't find variable: Buffer` which is being thrown in a util folder in the standard library. I've taken a look at the code and it's accessing Buffer from a global namespace. Thing is, I'm importing Buffer into the global namespace. Here's a look at my global.js

```
// Inject node globals into React Native global scope.
global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
global.process = require('process');
global.process.env.NODE_ENV = __DEV__ ? 'development' : 'production';

// Needed so that 'stream-http' chooses the right default protocol.
global.location = {
    protocol: 'file:',
};

// Don't do this in production. You're going to want to patch in
// https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-randombytes or similar.
global.crypto = {
    getRandomValues(byteArray) {
        for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            byteArray[i] = Math.floor(256 * Math.random());
        }
    },
};
```

My guess is the standard library is being evaluated before this global is being loaded in, and thus the error is thrown.

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you tried using rn-nodeify package instead of react nativify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back to this to leave a solution in case anyone is stuck on this. The solution was to essentially try to shim in different packages in different times to change the load order.

We tried going back to a different version when TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT was being treated differently and Buffer was more dependent on it. While on the older version we tried a lot of different things and eventually gave up and backtracked by updating buffer to the most recent version and finally everything worked.

What I mean to say is we're not sure how we fixed it, but it was by randomly changing the load order until we got lucky. Not a good answer, I'm aware, but the best I can provide for this issue.

Here's what our global.js looked like at the end

```
// Inject node globals into React Native global scope.
// Required for crypto functionality for bitcoinjs-lib, web3, etc.

global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
//global.Buffer.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT = false;

global.process = require('process');
global.process.env.NODE_ENV = __DEV__ ? 'development' : 'production';

var getRandomValues = function(byteArray) {
  var bytes = crypto.rng.randomBytes(byteArray.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
    byteArray[i] = bytes[i];
  }
};
// "But Zach, aren't you just doing the same thing twice?"
// Yes. Initializing the crypto-browserify module eventually requires
// crypto.getRandomValues to exist, so we must add it here once.
// However, crypto-browserify does not support getRandomValues, so we
// must re-add it after loading the module.
global.crypto = { getRandomValues };
global.crypto.rng = require('react-native-randombytes');
global.crypto = require('crypto');
global.crypto.getRandomValues = getRandomValues;
global.crypto.rng = require('react-native-randombytes');
crypto.rng.seedSJCL();

// Needed so that 'stream-http' chooses the right default protocol.
global.location = {
  protocol: 'file:'
};
```

Comment: i cant find global.js file

Comment: `global.js` is something you'd create and put at the root level. I ended up sun setting this project so if you'd like to take a look at how I did it - https://github.com/arshbot/hail

Answer (score 34):

In TypeScript I had to import `Buffer` explicitly.

```js
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
```

I would have expected that the compiler would complain about `Buffer` being missing before the import and/or that `"source.organizeImports": true` would have removed the line when saving the file, but neither were true.

@ehacinom's solution also worked.

Comment: What would be the reason of that unexpected behavior?

Comment: it actually worked after alot search Thank you.

Comment: This did not work for me. Another post also mentioned to place `global.Buffer = Buffer;` at the top of `app.js`, but didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

I ran `npm install buffer` and put this at the top of files that needed `Buffer`:

```
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer
```

Comment: I  am getting the same error, can you please explain which files will buffer. There are App.js, index.js and the other files

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue for me. But isn't importing buffer enough?

Answer (score 4):

I was using rn-nodeify to use node packages into my react-native project. After adding the postinstall script

```
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install buffer,events,process,stream,util,inherits,fs,path,assert --hack;"
```

I was still running into **Can't find variable: Buffer** . which I solved finally by importing the shim.js file into my App.js :

```
import './shim';
```

Hope it Helps ! Happy hacking.

Comment: import './shim' solved it for me as well. I imported it into my index.js and at first it wasn't doing anything, then I moved the import statement above the line 'import App from ./App' and it worked.

Comment: I already has the `"postinstall"` bit added to `package.json`, but after adding `import './shim';` it fixed it.

Comment: @faraza thank you! Been on this for hours and now finally working after adding to top of index js

Answer (score 1):

first install the following

```
yarn add buffer process babel-plugin-react-native-nodeify-hack
```

Then add to your babel settings `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-react-native-nodeify-hack"]
}
```

Import the buffer and process modules manually. In your `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js`, add this to the first line:

```
import process from 'process';
import buffer from 'buffer';
global.Buffer = buffer.Buffer
```

try to stop the running React Native Packager, and run:

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
```

and start it again

You are good to go!