# React native - “This browser lacks typed array (Uint8Array) support which is required by buffer v5.x. Use buffer v4.x if …”

Tags: react-native, webview, buffer

After implementing the webview I started to get this issue. If I run the app by using debugger then all work good but APK is falling.

below is my code for call API

```
handleButtonAction() {
    var token = AsyncStorage.getItem("loginJWT");
    var account_name = AsyncStorage.getItem("account_name");
    var password = AsyncStorage.getItem("password");

    //  alert(JSON.stringify(token));
    fetch(
      serverUrl +
        "/appapiv0/getLink?username=" +
        account_name +
        "&password=" +
        password,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Webview", {
          url: response.url
        });
      })
      .then(response => {
        return true;
      });
  }
```

webview.js

```
render() {
    var token = AsyncStorage.getItem('loginJWT');
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {this.renderHeader()}
        <WebView
          source={{  uri: "https:\/\/sexample.com\/dashboard",
          headers: {
          }}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Web view doesn't support typed array because web view is in-build browser, Use `DataView` instead of `TypedArray`

OR

Use BUFFER - `global.Buffer.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT = false`

OR

Otherwise try this - Upgrade react-native version from v5 to v6.

Comment: Where I have to define `global.Buffer.TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT = false`

Comment: follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432524/cant-find-variable-buffer