# React-Native: Can't find variable: Buffer

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with the variable Buffer. You can see it in the image below.
Can anybody help me???

[image: Error]

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any crypto library?

Comment: No. I want to use mqtt

Comment: okay there's a way which can surely solve your issue

Comment: Was this problem solved?

Comment: npm i -S buffer  ; 
import { Buffer } from "buffer"   ;  worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So buffer is core Node JS module, which means it’s probably C++ code bundled with the Node JS binary, not Javascript. The React Native packager can’t package it along with your app’s Javascript bundle, so you get a runtime error: Unable to resolve module .

To resolve this issue you need do this to make it run in react-native

```
npm i --save react-native-randombytes
react-native link react-native-randombytes

# install latest rn-nodeify 
npm i --save-dev tradle/rn-nodeify

# install node core shims and recursively hack package.json files 

 Now you need to run this command in your project directory

./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install
```

Final step

import this in your app.js

```
import './shim.js'
```

And in packaje.json 
 put this `postinstall:./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install`

Comment: I get this error:
_bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./shim.js` from `App.js`_

Comment: max provide the path of shim.js that creates when you run this command ```./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install```

Comment: Did this answer solve the problem? Also, which react-native library were you using?

Comment: @WISERDIVISOR read the text in the grey background all the libraries that need to be installed is mentioned chronically

Comment: @RishiSahu Thanks for the reply but I was talking about the library for MQTT.
Also, I found a library that allows me to implement MQTT without all the Buffers and Sockets that were needed here. Its `react_native_mqtt`. But be sure to use the web sockets port for the broker. Otherwise it won't even connect.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to install nodejs buffer. (`npm i -S buffer`)
Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432524/cant-find-variable-buffer)

Comment: I have already tried both options.
But when I add `global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require ('buffer').Buffer` in the corresponding module, I get the following error: _TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.version.slice')_